# Minecraft Coder Pack Terminal Memory Error Forge [Mac]

Tags: java, macos, memory, gradle, minecraft

I am trying to install mine craft coder pack for 1.7.10. I have src forge package downloaded and am using terminal. I used this to install it. http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Installation/Source I got to the part where you type in ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace --refresh-dependencies and it runs smoothly then stops at the end. I think it has to do with the allocated memory that java has. Here is what it says:

```
`Last login: Sun Mar 29 17:21:00 on ttys000
 craig-andersons-imac:~ CraigsFolder$ cd /Users/CraigsFolder/Desktop/forge 
 craig-andersons-imac:forge CraigsFolder$ ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace --refresh-dependencies
 Download http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/net/minecraftforge/gradle/ForgeGradle/1.2-SNAPSHOT/ForgeGradle-1.2-20150329.235405-283.jar
****************************
Powered By MCP:             
(can't insert link because of my reputation)
Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r, 
R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs
MCP Data version : unknown
****************************
:extractMcpData UP-TO-DATE
:getVersionJson
:extractUserDev UP-TO-DATE
:genSrgs SKIPPED
:extractNatives UP-TO-DATE
:getAssetsIndex
:getAssets
:makeStart SKIPPED
:downloadMcpTools SKIPPED
:downloadClient SKIPPED
:downloadServer SKIPPED
:mergeJars SKIPPED
:deobfuscateJar SKIPPED
:decompile SKIPPED
:processSources SKIPPED
:remapJar SKIPPED
:extractMinecraftSrc UP-TO-DATE
:recompMinecraft


The system is out of resources.
Consult the following stack trace for details.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope$ImportScope.makeEntry(Scope.java:385)
at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope.enter(Scope.java:196)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter$2.importFrom(MemberEnter.java:198)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter$2.enterAnnotation(MemberEnter.java:203)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:95)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:87)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:485)
at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:442)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:822)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:115)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:45)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:96)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:29)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:20)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:33)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:24)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:65)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:235)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:222)
:recompMinecraft FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':recompMinecraft'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -  -debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 8.426 secs
craig-andersons-imac:forge CraigsFolder$
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Adding the `[gradle]` tag since it is Gradle which is running out of memory.  You need to change the maximum heap i.e. -Xmx but I am not sure how to do this for gradle.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the procedure to give Gradle more memory.

1. Install Gradle (http://gradle.org/) *(You can google the install
   instructions)*
2. Go to your gradle folder and create the file `gradle.properties` and
   add this line to it: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2G` *(this gives Gradle
   2GB of memory)*
3. Run the Gradle by going to your work directory and type `gradle
   build` *(not `gradlew build`!)*